# Fixed points of a nonlinear system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the fixed points of a nonlinear two-dimensional system:

$$\dot{x} = \sin y$$
$$\dot{y} = x - x^3.$$

I know that $0 = x(1 - x²) \implies x = 0, 1, -1$. I am not sure what to do after this.

Comment: By fixed point, I think you mean the equilibrium points of the system, right? Then simply solve $\dot{x}=0$ and $\dot{y}=0$. Any solution would be an equilibrium. In your OP, there are infinite ones, such as $y=k\pi$ and $x=0,1,-1$. Of course, the stability of different equilibriums may be different. That would be another story.

Answer (score 2):

As usual for the system of differential equations to find its fixed points you need to solve the equation
$$
\mathbb f(\mathbb {\tilde x}) = \mathbb 0
$$
In your case it looks like

$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
\sin y & = & 0 \\
x-x^3 & = & 0
\end{array}\right. \quad \Longrightarrow \left[
\begin{array}{ccl}
y & = & \pi k,\ k \in \mathbb Z \\
x & = & \{-1,0,1\}
\end{array}
\right.
$

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of a fixed point/equilibrium/steady state/etc. we have
$$x(1 - {x^2})\mathop = \limits^{{\text{set}}} 0 \Rightarrow x = 0, \pm 1$$
and
$$\sin y\mathop = \limits^{{\text{set}}} 0 \Rightarrow y = n\pi, n \in {\mathbb Z}.$$
That is all you need to do.

Comment: How common is your $\mathop = \limits^{{\text{set}}}$ notation? It looks useful.

Comment: I have seen it a few times, but it is not common. I like it because we are actually "setting" $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ to zero. Writing $\dot x = 0$ and $\dot y = 0$ is ambiguous. It is also useful in optimization when you are setting derivatives to zero.